# Creating a logout button for SSO/SAML authenticated Angular js app

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

How do I add logout functionality to my angular app. I currently have a cookie(ngcookies) containing the saml-token, which is used to authenticate the app to the REST backend.

I have tried to just delete the cookie from the browser to test if this is enough to end a session, but it is somehow replaced. Is it angular that cache it and replaces it?

What else do i need to do to logout?